# Rails outside controller rendering i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render a view outside of a controller and can't seem to get i18n to work.  I'm using the feature noted here, https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18409, https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/new-feature-in-rails-5-render-views-outside-of-actions, https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderer.html

```
ABCController.render :index, assigns: {myvar: '12345'}
```

This is an example of what I'm doing.  The view renders fine in English and Spanish when accessed normally through a controller.  I'm actually using that render command inside another controller action to pass it to WickedPDF.  However, it always renders English.

Any help would be appreciated.  I looked through the documentation for render and https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18409 this pull request.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't try this, but it can solve your problem.

```
I18n.with_locale('es') do
  ABCController.render :index, assigns: { my_var: '12345' }
end
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn’t seem to work. I’ll try it again as I’m running out of options.

Comment: @user2185938 You can try to assign locale like this: `ABCController.render :index, assigns: { my_var: '12345', locale: :es }`

Comment: Tried that and also tried just forcing it in the view but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I wasn't setting locale for the one action I needed it.  It was a stupid oversight on my part.  It works just fine with I18n localization as long as you do it correctly.  Make sure all controller actions are properly localized and render works fine.  I thought I had my bases covered but I clearly didn't.